# Are [ssl-interception] and [tls-intercept] the same thing?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The following tags looks like duplicates to me:

- [ssl-interception](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssl-interception) (62 questions)

  > SSL Interception is a technique that can be used to intercept SSL sessions in order to inspect the encrypted traffic.
- [tls-intercept](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tls-intercept) (17 questions)

Is there some difference that I am missing here? Or should they be synonyms? If so, in what direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see a difference in usage. Some questions are even tagged with both.

Since [ssl](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssl) is a synonym for [tls](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tls), and tags are preferably nouns, I'd suggest to merge them with[tls-interception](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tls-interception) as a master and [ssl-interception](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssl-interception) as a synonym.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer) agrees. (Note the redirect.)

Comment: They're not synonyms, but they're colloquially interchangeable. Since all versions of SSL are deprecated in general use, tls-interception would be the correct term, and ssl-interception would be the legacy analog.

Comment: @RyanGooler "Synonym" ist the term on SE for tags which lead to the same set of questions. `SSL`, `TLS`, `HTTPS` and `SSLv3` are all marked as synonyms. This is does not mean the words mean exactly the same, which they obviously don't.

Comment: If nobody disagreed... why are they still separate? (bump)

Comment: @Michael-Where'sClayShirky You could flag the post for moderator attention and ask them to act on it.

Comment: @Arminius Done. I noticed because there's a HNQ where both tags are applied.

Comment: Somehow I never saw this until now. Apologies - completed :-)